# How to convert an arrayBuffer to readableStream in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, arraybuffer

I'm using [Pinata's `pinFileToIPFS()`](https://docs.pinata.cloud/api-pinning/pin-file) function that requires a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) to upload to Pinata's IPFS nodes. I have the bytearray of the file, for example of a PNG.
I want to convert this byteArray to readableStream and upload this on IPFS.
How can i convert that in typescript?

```
export async function putFileToIPFS(file:any): Promise<string>{
  readableStream = ** CONVERT FILE TO READABLE **
  let cid ;
  try {
  cid = await pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStream)
  console.log(cid)
  }   
  catch (error) { console.error(error);}
  return cid['IpfsHash']
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function putFileToIPFS(file: ArrayBuffer) {
  const readableStream = new ReadableBufferStream(file)
  ...
}

function ReadableBufferStream(ab: ArrayBuffer) {
  return new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
      controller.enqueue(ab)
      controller.close()
    }
  })
}
```

Alternatively, the "read size" could be controlled by setting a chunk size with multiple enqueues. This could potentially increase/decrease the number of HTTP requests sent by `pinFileToIPFS()`. [`subarray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray) maintains the memory footprint by reusing the underlying `ArrayBuffer`.

```
function ReadableBufferStream(ab: ArrayBuffer, chunkSize = 64*1024) { // 64 KiB
  return new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
      const bytes = new Uint8Array(ab)
      for (let readIndex = 0; readIndex < bytes.byteLength;) {
        controller.enqueue(bytes.subarray(readIndex, readIndex += chunkSize))
      }
      controller.close()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: for the first implementation I receive this error :  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined

Comment: Are you running in the browser or via command line (Deno/NodeJS)?